# Does Visual Studio for Mac Preview have Web Deploy?

Tags: webdeploy, visual-studio-mac

I am new to using a Mac and trying to setup a coworking to publish a shared .net core web app so that it publishes to the azure account. I have downloaded the azure publishing profile but do not see Publish or Web Deploy in the GUI. How do I deploy the app to azure?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: From what I could tell it does not. I ended up installing parallels with Windows 10 and do development on that. There are lots of simple things that VS for Mac does differently like css color or html format function that made it very difficult to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to publish to Azure directly from `Visual Studio for Mac`.

[image: Right mouse button click on the project -> Publish -> Publish to Azure...]

Comment: Any idea on how to deploy it locally on Mamp or on a Apache server ? I don't use Azure (too expensive for a proof of concept project + I work alone).